# Surgery on smooth four-manifold preserves the intersection form

Tags: smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology, surgery-theory, 4-manifolds

In [these notes](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/swnotes.pdf) (p. 190), it is claimed that (possibly with superfluous hypotheses):

> **Claim.** Let $M$ be a closed connected oriented smooth 4-manifold and let $c\colon S^1\hookrightarrow M$ be an embedding representing a non-trivial homology class. Then performing a surgery on $c$ does not affect $H_2(M)/\mathrm{Tors}$ nor the intersection form $q_M$.

Precisely, we are looking for an isomorphism  $H_2(M)/\mathrm{Tors}\cong H_2(M')/\mathrm{Tors}$ such that $q_M\cong q_M'$. By surgery, I mean that one finds a tubular neightborhood $N\cong S^1\times D^3$ of $c$ in $M$ and construct a new smooth manifold
$M'=(M\setminus N)\cup_{\partial N} (D^2\times S^2)$.

**How does one show that?** I can only show that such an isomorphism exists, but not that it preserves the intersection form (see below).

---

*Partial proof.* Denote respectively by $b_i$ and $b_i'$ the $i$-Betti number of $M$ and $M'$. Since $H_2(M)/\mathrm{Tors}$ is a free abelian group of rank $b_2$, it suffices to show that $b_2=b_2'$. Using Van Kampen's theorem, we find that
$$
\pi_1(M)\cong\pi_1(M\setminus N)*_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}\cong\pi_1(M\setminus N)
$$

and
$$
\pi_1(M)\cong\pi_1(M\setminus N)*_\mathbb{Z}0\cong\pi_1(M\setminus N)/[c],
$$

where $[c]$ is the image of $c$ in $\pi_1$. Using that $c$ represents a non-trivial homology class, we deduce that $b_1'=b_1-1$. By Poincaré duality, we also have that $b_3'=b_3-1$.

On the other hand, we compute that $\chi(M)=\chi(M\setminus N)+\chi(N)-\chi(\partial N)$ and $\chi(M')=\chi(M\setminus N)+\chi(D^2\times S^2)-\chi(\partial N)$, where $\chi(N)=\chi(S^1)=0$ and $\chi(D^2\times S^2)=\chi(S^2)=2$. It follows that $\chi(M')=\chi(M)+2$.

$M$ and $M'$ being closed connected manifold, we have $b_0=b_0'=b_4=b_4'=1$. With all of
the above, we find that $b_2=b_2'$.

Comment: One way to argue is that the 2 dimensional homology classes in the manifold generically miss the curve, so you can assume that they are represented by the same maps, and so they will have the same intersections as well.

Comment: Hmm and what about the surface $\{*\}\times S^2$ coming from the gluing of $D^2\times S^2$ in $M'$? It seems to me like an additional 2-dim homology class representative...

Comment: Presuming that you intended $*$ to be the center of $D^2$, and picking instead $p$ on the boundary of $D^2$, that $\{*\} \times S^2$ is isotopic  (hence homologous) in $M'$ to $\{p\} \times S^2 \subset S^1 \times S^2$, and then it can be further isotoped to the other side  of $S^1 \times S^2$. Hence this is not a new 2-dimensional homology class.

Comment: I don't fully understand your argument. As $\{p\}\times S^2$ is nullhomotopic in $S^1\times D^3\subset M$, we would like $\{p\}\times S^2$ to be nullhomotopic in $M'$. Why would that be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer ellaborates on @Cheerful_Parsnip's comment.

We can find surfaces $\Sigma_1,\ldots,\Sigma_{b_2}$ such that their homology classes $[\Sigma_i]$ define a basis of $H_2(M)/\mathrm{Tors}$. In that case, the intersection form is the matrix $\left((\Sigma_i\cdot\Sigma_j)\right)_{ij}$, where $(\Sigma_i\cdot\Sigma_j)$ is the algebraic intersection of $\Sigma_i$ and $\Sigma_j$.
Moreover, the $\Sigma_i$'s generically do not intersect $c$ (by comparing dimensions), and we may assume they do not intersect $N$. After surgery, the $\Sigma_i$'s are untouched, and still have the same algebraic intersections.

To conclude, it remains to check that the classes $[\Sigma_i]$'s still define a basis of $H_2(M')/\mathrm{Tors}$.
On one hand, since the intersection form is unimodular and in particular has a non-zero determinant, the family $[\Sigma_i]$'s remains free in $H_2(M')/\mathrm{Tors}$. On the other hand, as we showed already $b_2=b_2'$, this family must also be generating. This concludes.

---

**Additional comment:** we answer why the class of $\{p\}\times S^2$, for $p\in D^2$, is zero in $M'$ (asked in the comments, ellaborating on @Lee Mosher's answer).
First, we may isotope $\{p\}\times S^2$ and assume $p\in c$. Then, recall that the Poincaré dual of $c$ can be represented as a 3-submanifold $Y\subset M$ such that $Y\cap N=\{p\}\times D^3$. Finally, we consider $Y\setminus N$ as a submanifold of $M'$ and check that $\partial(Y\setminus N)\cong\{p\}\times S^2$.